# Is ccTLD and gTLD hierarchical

Tags: networking, dns

I read that in DNS, below root server in hierarchy, there comes TLDs. That is generic and country code TLD...

I am confused, because I see many websites like gov.uk, org.in etc.
If they are separate TLDs, then how can we define such hierarchical names.
Both gTLD and ccTLD are at same level in hierarchy right?!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

They are not TLDs, they are second level domains. The TLDs are `uk` and `in` in your examples, then `gov.uk` is second level domain or also known as `subdomain`. It depends on the registry of the TLD if it will allow domain registrations it the TLD or only in some "special" second level domain or both.

As far as the DNS is involved `gov.uk` is the same as `something.com`. You have `root servers`, then the `uk (com) TLD servers`, then `the name servers of gov.uk (something.com)` and then the NS records an the `gov.uk (something.com)` DNS zone answering for the third level subdomains like `third-level.gov.uk` and `third-level.something.com`.

The only difference is as I mentioned above the will of the registry to sell second or third (or in the case of `uk`) both level domains.

Comment: "gov.uk is the same as something.com" not necessarily exactly true in all cases. A dot does not imply necessarily a delegation. See `gouv.fr` and `fr`, there is no delegation. Also, the subdomain can be open to registration but handled by another registry. See `za` vs `co.za` or `uk.com` vs `com`.